# Initialization array bounds in Ada

Tags: java, arrays, types, linked-list, ada

I am having a problem while writing a package for doubly circular linked lists in ada.
I am specifically writing a function that will take my DCLL and return the contents of it in array form.
In my spec file I created the type like this

```
type ListArray is array(Integer range <>) of Integer;
```

My problem is, I keep getting "length check failed" errors when the client calls my package.
Here is the client program(part)

```
procedure tester is

   LL : sorted_list.List;
   larray : sorted_list.ListArray(1..sorted_list.length(LL));

   begin
   sorted_list.Insert(LL, 5);
   larray:= sorted_list.toArray(LL);
   end;
```

I know this is failing because when I define larray and set it to the length, the length is 0 because LL doesn't have anything in it yet. 
In java I would just initialize the array in the body of the code after the insertion but it seems in ada I cannot do that (or at least I don't know how)
Is there anyway to create an array in ada without defining the bound and then define the bounds in the body after insertion?

I hope I have explained my problem well enough for you to understand.
Thanks.

Comment: isn't it possible to use dynamic allocation for arrays, like malloc in C/C++ ?

Comment: @mangusta I don't know. That is my question. As far as I have researched I don't see how.

Comment: @Cheesegraterr You can declare an access type to `ListArray` and use `new` to allocate it dynamically.  But you don't need to, because you can declare a variable-size array as I demonstrate in my answer, and the array will automatically be deallocated when you leave the block.

Comment: @mangusta You use `malloc` in C++?  Tsk, tsk.

Comment: @ajb I use both malloc and new :)

Comment: What this question has to do with Java? also what is ADA? (programming language is Ada)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
procedure tester is

    LL : sorted_list.List;

begin
    sorted_list.Insert(LL, 5);
    declare
        larray : sorted_list.ListArray(1..sorted_list.length(LL));
    begin
        larray := sorted_list.toArray(LL);
        -- code that uses larray must be in this block
    end;
end;
```

or

```
procedure tester is

    LL : sorted_list.List;

begin
    sorted_list.Insert(LL, 5);
    declare
        larray : sorted_list.ListArray := sorted_list.toArray(LL);
            -- no need to specify the bounds, it will take them from the bounds
            -- of the result returned by toArray
    begin
        -- code that uses larray must be in this block
    end;
end;
```

A couple things to note: (1) The declarations in the block (beginning with `declare`) are evaluated at the point where a statement would be executed (in fact, a block *is* one kind of statement), so it will use the `LL` that has been set up at that point.  (2) The variable `larray` is visible only inside the block where you declared it.